# Notarize issue: CommandLineTools not in PATH

Tags: command-line, xcode, path

**OSX version: 10.14.6**

I've been trying to `notarize` an `Electron` app using the latest version of [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/), however I keep getting the error:

> error: unable to find utility "altool", not a developer tool or in
> PATH

I've removed, reinstalled and selected the CommandLineTools using:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools   
xcode-select --install   
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Check the path:

```
xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

This is in the 'Library' directory at the root level of the drive, not the "user" account "Library" directory. So that's all good (I guess) but I still get the above error. Also, if I look in the directory `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` I do not see this "altool". Is it somewhere else?

Am I doing something obviously wrong? If I output the PATH (below) I don't see any reference to the CommandLineTools directory. Is it odd that the installer pkg did not do that?

Sorry to be so long-winded but I've been stuck on this for days. I'm hesitant to "try anything" but I am getting to that point. Can someone steer me right?

> echo "$PATH"
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin

Comment: altool does not come with the CLT.  It is part of Xcode.

Comment: @MarcWilson – oh geez, really?! I've seen **nothing** about that in all my searches. Arrgh. Off to get Xcode. Thanks.